# Can Hyperledger "Smart Contract" have multiple collections at the state?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to understand the way a hyperledger state should be used.
I want to develop a simple blockchain network for voting.
And as far as I understand a blockchain plays a 'database' role of an application.
All my previous experience tell me to build a database with several *collections* (or tables):

- for voters (users of a web app, that shouldn't have any specific certificate)
- for election (e.g. "election for best restaurant around"),
- for candidates,
- for the votes itself (e.g. Bill votes for 'Old Bob sandwiches')
- etc.

I have read a lot of articles at `https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io`
And they always show the case where there are a lot of **Commercial Papers** or **Cars** that can be bought and issued.
I've seen that there are "private collections" allowed, but I don't need the data to be private.
I've also seen that there are channels (but channels, again, make different users interact with different ledgers)

A code from the example [repo](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/contract/lib/papercontract.js):

```
class CommercialPaperContext extends Context {
  constructor() {
    super();
      // All papers are held in a list of papers
      this.paperList = new PaperList(this);
  }
}
...
class CommercialPaperContract extends Contract {
  createContext() {
    return new CommercialPaperContext();
  }
...
  async buy(ctx, issuer, paperNumber, currentOwner, newOwner, price, purchaseDateTime)
```

See - there are `buy` method with `issuer` parameter, but there is no `issuer` collection, and no `owners` collection. There are also no 'money balance' states anywhere in the app.

I would like to take a look at the application that works with data of different types (Cars/Customers/Shops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hyperledger fabric data is stored as a key value pair.

Key has to be unique for every transaction.State is maintained for that key.
You can use rich queries to get data from state.

You can define any asset like cars,books etc with their attributes(collections)in the chaincode and store it too,mostly in a json format.
Provided that the key is unique.
You could check the fabcar or the marbles02 chaincode for the same,you would find it in fabric-samples/chaincode.
Revert on comments if I have missed anything.